# Node creates new mysql connections on parallel executions, and doesn't end the new connections

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-connector, loopback

I'm trying to write a program using `loopback - node - mysql` wherein parallel DB(MySQL) calls are made. There is already a persistent connection between node and MySQL. When the parallel calls are made, additional connections to MySQL DB are created to fulfill the request. But on completion of the parallel calls and function, the new connections made to MySQL still persist. So on the long run a lot of connections are made to MySQL DB which aren't closed after use.
Here is My Code

```
function getSubTypeIdAndOrderForNewTimelineStory(gameId, name) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  async.parallel([
  function (callback) {
    getTimelineStorySubType(name).then(function (timelineStorySubType) {
      callback(null, timelineStorySubType.id);
    }).fail(function (error) {
      callback(error);
    });
  },
function (callback) {
  getLastTimeLineStory(gameId).then(function (gameTimelineStory) {
    callback(null, gameTimelineStory? gameTimelineStory.order+1: 1);
  }).fail(function (error) {
     callback(error);
  });
 }
], function (error, result) {
  if(error){
  deferred.reject(error);
}
else {
  var response = {
    gameTimelineStorySubTypeId : result[0],
    order : result[1]
  }
  deferred.resolve(response);
 }
});
return deferred.promise;
}
```

So either i need to know the number of existing unused connections or set a timeOut in mysql to terminate unused connections.
Thanks

Comment: You can use [loopback transactions](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-database-transactions.html) to make sure that you finish each connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dataSource object you can find free connections which needs to be removed from the pool.

```
function removeOpenDatabaseConnections(dataSource){
 var freeConections = dataSource.connector.client._freeConnections;
 freeConections.forEach(function (freeConnection) {
  freeConnection._removeFromPool();
 }); 
}
```